# MySQL timestamp to PHP DateTime

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I am getting data from an external MySQL table with a created_field of type timestamp with example data in the following format '2015-10-01 07:45:22'

I then want to convert this into a PHP DateTime Object for persisting into a database using Doctrine ORM.

The weird thing is, whatever I try to do, the date being saved ends up being the current date and not the timestamp in the database.

Here's what I have tried:

```
$date = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s',$result['created_at']);
```

And

```
$date = new \DateTime($result['created_at']);
```

Maybe I am tired but can't believe I cannot figure this out! Someone please help

Comment: Verify the contents of `$result['created_at']` again

Comment: Believe me, I have done it so many time

Comment: Check it again, because both your solutions work. The alternative is that you ORM is doing something wrong, but you only shared code of the DateTime object so I assume you debugged it and verified it is wrong at that point

Comment: replace it with your example ('2015-10-01 07:45:22'), maybe you override it somewhere

Comment: What do you get when you use strtotime()? It's very forgiving, and will point out format errors that will break createFromFormat().

Comment: Okay, guys, I know you will want to kill me and I am sorry for wasting your time. @PeeHaa mentioning ORM reminded me that I'd set lifecycleCallbacks for the created_value on my database. I wasn't checking whether it was null before setting the value to current time. I am so so sorry and thanks for your time

Comment: It happens @MasindeMuliro

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert this string to timestamp and then create a DateTime object from it.
Here is an example:

```
$timestamp = strtotime('Mon, 12 Dec 2011 21:17:52 +0000');
$dt = new DateTime();
$dt->setTimestamp($timestamp);
```

I hope this helps.